# Does one need Access to access Access files with odbc?

Tags: ms-access

Is it necessary to have Access installed when using odbc connector to access Access files?

I have an Access file db, which is used by my application. I want to install this application on another pc, so I also need to move the file.

Will I be able to access Access file if I copy the file and have my application installed together with odbc connector? Or do I also need Access (for some dlls?) to do that?

Comment: Does one need Excel to excel at Excel? (Sorry I just couldn't resist it...)

Comment: It's like that on purpose :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is  . . . longer.

If your app using the MDB file for storage **only** then all you need on the clients machine is MSDAO - [Microsoft Data Access Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Data_Access_Components).
There are different versions of DAO libs for different version of Access, you should be able to lookup which version you require for your version of access easily enough.

Later versions of MS Windows often come with DAO libs already installed.

If your app is firing up MSAccess Forms or Reports in the database then you do need to have MS Access installed

Answer (score 1):

While the answer about using DAO is correct, you also have the choice of using ADO and optionally ADOX, supplied by Microsoft as part of the MDAC package.  It has a smaller memory footprint than DAO and is usually faster.  The same restrictions apply in that you can read and write data, create, modify, and drop tables, but not use Access forms or reports.

ADO is still supported as a COM based interface for Access and many other databases.  ADOX (for table modification) is depreciated, but still works.

ADOX and DAO are both "Jet only" interfaces, meaning that they work with Microsoft Access's "Jet DB Engine", but will not work if you later change the underlying database.

The OBDC connector you mention should work well, using ADO.NET (recommended for new code) and still has the same "data only" restrictions.  This interface should still work if you later want to change the database to SQL server or MySQL.